# How to use authorization header

Tags: php, api, curl, postman

I have a curl command:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.*****.com/servers/d13****-9703******/power-on" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Apikey a****************3"
```

The code I tried is:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.*****.com/servers/d13****-9703******/power-on");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
headers = array(
  'Authentication:Apikey 3****************fa',
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

if ($server_output === false) {
  print_r('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}

curl_close ($ch);
print_r($server_output);
```

It returns "Unauthenticated".

The key is ok. I tested on Postman and it's ok.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXTSX.png

Here is my code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQPdM.png

the api provider accepts both dataform and object input data

Comment: Did you test the api with postman ?

Comment: as i said and upload image yes it works with postman
 I tested on Postman and it's ok.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXTSX.png